# Cannot instantiate the type HttpClient

Tags: java, eclipse, httpclient

I have added the .jars to my library and I can also instantiate other classes in the JAR. What gives? I've tried to clean the project etc.

It's a compiler-time error. Eclipse won't let me instantiate it.

I'm importing the correct library, not the sun version, and using the default contructor, specified by their [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html)

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

(Eclipse, mac, Apache HTTP, "HttpClient 4.0.1 (GA)" downloaded from [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi))

Comment: Please paste the compile time error into your question.

Comment: Moved from "Answer"
 1. Can we have the error message?
 2. Are you working in an IDE?
 3. Do you know there're differences among compilation, IDE runtime, application runtime?
 4. It shouldn't be a Mac issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960149/cannot-instantiate-the-type-listproduct

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`HttpClient` is an interface in 4.x, use `DefaultHttpClient` for instances.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Comment: `Warning: The type DefaultHttpClient is deprecated`

Comment: it's goofy their documentation and getting started guide still don't mention this, it just say says `The no argument constructor for HttpClient provides a good set of defaults for most situations so that is what we'll use.
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`

Comment: DefaultHttpClient is deprecated

Answer (score 9):

If you are using 4.3, one way to initialize it is:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

The quick start guide for 4.3 is located at:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/quickstart.html

Answer (score 3):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

They haven't documented this anywhere on the website, but I've imported the source, and the javadoc, and this was the example in the Javadoc for the HttpClient class.

Comment: Be aware of breaking changes in such projects, always check for the correct version when reading docs, tutorials etc.

Good API design is hard, and avoiding breaking changes even harder, unfortunately.

Comment: I think I'll stick with the legacy one, since all the tutorials are 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Put in ayour attention that depending on your demands you should instance httpCleint with HttpParams, and/or connection manager. It can be useful in case of thultithreading access, when default settings doesn't fit.

You can find more info in documentation here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/