# Cannot instantiate the type List<Product>

Tags: java, list, initialization, ejb

I have the following code:

```
List<Product> product = new List<Product>();
```

The error:

```
Cannot instantiate the type List<Product>
```

`Product` is an Entity in my EJB project. Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Glad this was asked. As a dev moving from c# to java, it isn't immediately clear that list is an interface in this language.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK it is if you [read the documentation `:)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: Needing to read the documentation before using a list is nothing but a sign of poor design.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

[`List` is an interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Interfaces cannot be instantiated. Only concrete types can be instantiated. You probably want to use an [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which is an *implementation* of the `List` interface.

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

Answer (score 21):

Use a concrete list type, e.g. `ArrayList` instead of just `List`.

Answer (score 18):

List is an interface. You need a specific class in the end so 
either try

```
List l = new ArrayList();
```

or

```
List l = new LinkedList();
```

Whichever suit your needs.

Comment: We can do it both ways cant we? I was just giving an answer to the problem. Actually one of the answers.

Comment: Raw collection types are dangerous and should not be used or suggested for use in any new code targeted for Java 5+, end of story.

Comment: Should be avoided, yes. What about the pre-generics Java applications? Bottom line is there are two ways to instantiate this kind of statement and they both are valid. There is another question of which one should be used whenever possible. And that's generics.

Comment: @Matt Ball Ok man, let it die. We have to cover all aspects though. Regards!

Comment: Cannot do it. It returns error "type missing argument for generic class"

Answer (score 10):

List can be instantiated by any class implementing the interface.By this way,Java provides us polymorphic behaviour.See the example below:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Instead of instantiating an ArrayList directly,I am using a List to refer to ArrayList object so that we are using only the List interface methods and do not care about its actual implementation.

Examples of classes implementing List are ArrayList,LinkedList,Vector.You probably want to create a List depending upon your requirements.

Example:- a LinkedList is more useful when you hve to do a number of inertion or deletions .Arraylist is more performance intensive as it is backed by a fixed size array and array contents have to be changed by moving or regrowing the array.

Again,using a List we can simply change our object instantiation without changing any code further in your programs.

Suppose we are using `ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();`

we may use a specific method of ArrrayList and out code will not be robust

By using `List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();`

we are making sure we are using only List interface methods..and if we want to change it to a LinkedList we simply have to change the code :

```
List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
```

------ your code uses List interface methods.....

```
value = new LinkedList<String>();
```

-----your code still uses List interface methods and we do not have to change anything----
and we dont have to change anything in our code further

By the way a LinkedList also works a Deque which obviously also you cannot instantiate as it is also an interface

Comment: This is called "programming to interface" design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces can not be directly instantiated, you should instantiate classes that implements such Interfaces.

Try this:

```
NameValuePair[] params = new BasicNameValuePair[] {
        new BasicNameValuePair("param1", param1),
        new BasicNameValuePair("param2", param2),
};
```