# Cannot instantiate the type ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer

I try to create an ExpandableListView in a navigation drawer. I tried a sample code but i got this error before the compile.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

   listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

> The error is in this line:  listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

Why it says that Cannot instantiate the type ExpandableListAdapter ?

Comment: you cant instantiate an Interface.

Comment: rename `ExpandableListAdapter`

Comment: I renamed it with ExpandableListAdapter listAdapterr; but it din't work.

Comment: remove the import of ExpandableListAdapter it seem it takes default interface ExpandableListAdapter import.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot instantiate the type List<Product>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960149/cannot-instantiate-the-type-listproduct)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ExpandableListAdapter` is also a interface in the [android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) It seems that you are importing this, and this is trying to be instantiated instead your local ExpandableListAdapter class.

Rename your `ExpandableListAdapter`.

Comment: You're right. I changed  ExpandableListAdapter class name because I tried to use  android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter instead of my class.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;` or rename your class under this name.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Because [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html)  is an `interface`, aka has no implementation.

Check the documentation for some implementations of `ExpandableListAdapter` like [SimpleExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) .