# Cannot instantiate the type

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I have tried to solve this error, and even with research, my attempts have been unsuccessful. In particular, I am receiving the following error:
Cannot instantiate the type List

Below is the code:

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {


    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;   
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
         //create list variable
         mUsers = new List<ParseUser>(); 



    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();


        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    //add all the users to your list variable 
                    mUsers.addAll(users); 

                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                }
            }
        });

        //check the size of your list to see how big it is before accessing it
        final int size = mUsers.size(); 

       //or use a loop to loop through each one
        for(ParseUser mParseUser : mUsers)
        {
              //skip over the current user
           if(mParseUser == ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
               continue; 

           mParseUser.getString("name");
           mParseUser.getNumber("age"); 
           mParseUser.getString("headline");
        }

    }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

**Update**

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {


    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;   
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
         //create list variable
        mUsers = (List<ParseUser>) findViewById(R.id.listView1);



    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();


        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {



                  //add all the users to your list variable 
                    mUsers.addAll(users); 



                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                }
            }
        });

        //check the size of your list to see how big it is before accessing it
        final int size = mUsers.size(); 

       //or use a loop to loop through each one
        for(ParseUser mParseUser : mUsers)
        {
              //skip over the current user
           if(mParseUser == ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
               continue; 

           mParseUser.getString("name");
           mParseUser.getNumber("age"); 
           mParseUser.getString("headline");

           ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                   this, 
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Unsure what to input here, 
                   as I want to return all three items (name, age, headline) from parse into the list);
           mUsers.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

    }
    }
```

An error prompted
The method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter) is undefined for the type List

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot instantiate `Interface List` with `new List()`

The keyword `new` is for creating (instantiating) object. In this case, you can instantiate `Interface List` with any class that `implements List`

```
mUsers = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(); //example with ArrayList
```

See **All Known Implementing Classes:** of `List` in Java api [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/List.html).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, and clarification. That has greatly helped resolved the error. If you don't mind me asking, how would I relate the arraylist in my layout so that the information populated through parse would be displayed in the actual application, since as of now it is blank.

Comment: @user3827788 This [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app?lq=1) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-arraylist) will help you to use `ListView`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of ListView. I have looked at both links, and have tried to incorporate that into my code, but have encountered a few issues, and confusions. I have added my updated code under the update section of my initial post. It would helpful if you could take a look it, and kindly advise.

Comment: @user3827788 It would be better if you post as a new question to be elegant, as there are problems in your code of `findViewById()` and `setAdapter` method calls.

Answer (score 1):

List is an interface. Interfaces cannot be instantiated.

So Try this:

```
mUsers = new ArrayList<ParseUser>();
```

Instead of

```
mUsers = new List<ParseUser>();
```

Reference: [Cannot instantiate the type List<Product>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960149/cannot-instantiate-the-type-listproduct)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, and clarification. That has greatly helped resolved the error. If you don't mind me asking, how would I relate the arraylist in my layout so that the information populated through parse would be displayed in the actual application, since as of now it is blank.

Comment: You can use ListView in your layout page for displaying the result

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of ListView. I have tried to incorporate that into my code, but have encountered a few issues, and confusions. I have added my updated code under the update section of my initial post. It would helpful if you could take a look it, and kindly advise.