# Maven installing java library fully of unimplemented abstract classes?

Tags: java, maven, apache-httpclient-4.x

In my project I'm using HttpClient and when I list it as a dependency like so

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This was after I downloaded the jar file locally and ran maven install on it. When I try to use the library inside my rest server, or moreover, when I try to instantiate HttpClient like

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

I get a cannot instantiate abstract class error. And when looking into the actual files of the library, they're just a bunch of unimplemented abstract classes.

What's the easiest way I can go about getting HttpClient as a library and able to be used in my code?

Thanks for any help, 
Adam

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot instantiate the type httpclient in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131689/cannot-instantiate-the-type-httpclient-in-android)

Comment: The title of this question is nowhere near the actual problem you are having. You should consider editing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot instantiate the type HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276903/cannot-instantiate-the-type-httpclient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this to instantiate HttpClient

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

you can not create an instance directly as its an abstract class for more information about

or you can use

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

> ApacheHttpClinet

please refer this [nice tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/)

Comment: Ok thank you. It does happen to say that the DefaultHttpClient() is deprecated though.

Comment: Compiler is complaining that HttpClientBuilder has protected access in its class